# How do you test N significant digits for a float value?

Tags: python, python-unittest

Lots of code (e.g. `numpy`, `scipy`, `sklearn`) does math processing where the result is a float or an array of float. In `unittest.TestCase` there is a method for comparing float values called [`assertAlmostEqual`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual) but this does not test for significant digits

Checking the significant digits is important because:

- some values are going to be in the range of 1e-9 and so looking at the N digits (i.e. 0.0000000) after the decimal point will not help here because all the minimum values start at 1e-9

### How do you test N significant digits for a float value?

Comment: I feel like maybe there's some misunderstanding about how `allclose` works. It will function just fine even if the numbers being compared are on the order of 1e-12. Can you add some detail about what you're actually trying to do? Do you want to compare two numbers up to a specified significant digit count?

Answer (score 2):

i found the best way is to use `numpy.testing.assert_approx_equal` because it is specifically implemented to test significant digits.

example code:

```
import numpy.testing as npt
actual = 1.23456e-9
expected = 1.234567e-9
npt.assert_approx_equal(actual, expected, significant=7)
```

note: documentation for the `numpy.testing.assert_approx_equal` function has a disclaimer

> It is recommended to use one of assert_allclose, assert_array_almost_equal_nulp or assert_array_max_ulp instead of this function for more consistent floating point comparisons.

I have not used these other functions so I can not offer advice on these other functions.

Comment: [Very interesting implementation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.0/numpy/testing/_private/utils.py#L540-L638) when one would naively expect something like `relative_error < 10**-significant`

Answer (score -3):

You can test whether a floating-point value has N significant digits in Python by converting it to a string, manipulating the string, and then evaluating the result. Here's a general function to do this

```
def has_n_significant_digits(value, n):
    value_str = str(value)
    trimmed_str = value_str.lstrip('0').rstrip('0')
    parts = trimmed_str.split('.')
    significant_digits = len(''.join(parts))
    return significant_digits >= n

value = 0.00345
n = 3
result = has_n_significant_digits(value, n)
print(result)
```

Comment: That's not at all what OP was asking for. They're asking for an equality test with a specified number of significant digits, not a method to determine how many significant digits one number has.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy